# how to hide border of unselected part using css in E4 RCP

Tags: css, border, rcp, selected, e4

[image]
I have two parts in a perspective, one on top and other at the bottom. When bottom part is selected, the border at the bottom should be enabled. When the top part is selected, the border at top should be selected. But in E4 RCP, any one part is selected by setting attributes in css, but the border of both parts is selected.How to remove/hide border from unselected part.

PFB the css used.

```
.MPartStack {    
  swt-tab-renderer: null;
  swt-selected-tabs-background: #FFFFFF #c1cbd8 0%;
  swt-simple: false;
  swt-mru-visible: false;
  swt-shadow-visible: false;
  swt-tab-outline: #D6DDE5;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px;  
  swt-maximize-visible: false;
  swt-minimize-visible: false;
  swt-tab-height: 20px;
}

.MPartStack.active {
     swt-selected-tabs-background: #c1cbd8 100%;
}

.MPartStack.active.noFocus {
     swt-selected-tabs-background: #FFFFFF #c1cbd8 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Which border? The border around the actual part or some part of the part stack tabs?

Comment: The border is around the entire part at the top and bottom.We just need the border in selected part ie part with focus alone.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly which border, I think a picture would help. It may be necessary to use a custom renderer. Either the `swt-tab-renderer` or something like the part or sash renderer.

Comment: Hi, I have attached image. Border is visible in part stack above and part stack below.